# Discrete mathematics. Just an impression, or this is always true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I feel that the following is always true:

$$ \frac{2^k-1}{3} \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod }2) \text{ if }k \equiv 0 ~(\text{mod }2) \wedge k \geq 2$$

I've just tried it using a "brute force" approach, but I'm not able to prove it in a formal way.
Where can I start?

Comment: @DonAntonio My bad, I must have been sleepy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 
\frac{2^k-1}{3} \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod }2) \hspace{10mm}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{10mm} 2^k-1 \equiv 3 \equiv 1~(\text{mod }2) \hspace{10mm}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{10mm} 2^k \equiv 0 ~(\text{mod }2).
$$
The last claim is certainly true. By the way, it is true for all $k\ge 1$.

Comment: The first $\Leftrightarrow$ is only $\Rightarrow$ since $a=1\pmod{2}$ does not imply that $\frac{a}3=1\pmod{2}$ because $\frac{a}3$ might not be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2^k-1}3=\frac{0-1}1\pmod 2=-1=1\pmod2$$

Comment: why do you substitute $2^k$ with $0$?

Comment: Because you're doing arithmetic modulo $\;2\;$ and thus $\;2^k=0\pmod 2\;$ ...!

Comment: This replacement of the numerator and the denominator of a ratio by their residues is not legal.

Comment: Says who, @did? As long as things are well defined, as in this case, replacement is valid as far as I can see. Besides, the replacements by their residues is because we're interested in their residues (modulo 2, in this case)

Comment: $$\frac73=\frac{2^3-1}3=\frac{0-1}1=1\pmod{2}?$$

Comment: @Did Are you asking whether what you wrote above is correct? Because the answer is yes...

Comment: Actually I gave an example which shows that the rules you applied without qualm are in fact absurd (that is, if one applies them without due precautions outside of their domain of validity). So... you really think that $\frac73=1\pmod{2}$? Well... Hence $\frac13=\frac73-2=1\pmod{2}$, right? Hence $\frac23=2\cdot\frac13=2\cdot1=0\pmod{2}$. That is, $\frac23=2n$ for some integer $n$. Thus, $n=\frac13$ is an integer? Nice.

Comment: No, I think you're misunderstanding big time, @Did: Of course $\;\frac23=\pmod2\;$ as this **actually** means $\;2\cdot3^{-1}\pmod 2=2\cdot1^{-1}\pmod 2=0\cdot 1\pmod 2=0\pmod 2\;$. I mean, this is basic algebra...or am I missing something?? After all we have a field here and we can do **all** the usual *legal* operation within it. You seem to be relating all to the integers. Why? I can't tell.

Comment: Then you are not answering the question at all. The question asks about some property of the real numbers $\frac{2^k-1}3$ (OK, *rational* numbers if you like). To show that they are odd integers, the first task is to show that they are integers. Unfortunately, your solution omits this step. (Note that another solution on the page does the same, actually only the *least* upvoted solution deals seriously with the question at present, which is an edifying state of affairs if you ask me...)

Comment: @Did Ah, so you mean about *the question* itself...Well, then yes: I agree with you: first step would be to show that fraction is actually an integer, yet I thought this step would rather be the easy one as the question's tag is "modular arithmetic/discrete mathematics", so looking at the powers of two modulo three would do the trick. Another more elementary tagging would, perhaps, have drawn my attention to that point.

Answer (score 1):

When k is even,
 $$ 2^k = 2^{2n} = 4^n $$

Factoring (when n > 0):

$$
    4^n - 1 = (4-1) \times (1 + 4 + ... + 4^{n-1})
    = 3 \times (1 + 4x)
$$
(for some integer x), which gives us:
$$
{{2^k-1}\over 3} = {{(4^n -1)}\over{3}} = 1 + 4x = 1\mod 2
$$

When k is odd, k = (2n+1)

$$
    2^k - 1 = 2^{2 n + 1} - 1 = 4^n\times 2 - 1 = 4^n + 4^n - 1 = 4^n + 3\times(1+4x)
$$
and
$$
    {{2^k-1}\over 3} = {{4^n + 3\times(1+4x)}\over 3} = {{4^n}\over 3} + (1+4x)
$$

Since
$$
4^n \neq 0 \mod 3,
$$
this is never an integer, so
$$
{{2^k-1}\over 3} \neq  1\mod 2
$$